# inconsistent error of : TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a python code with the following two classes.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class QNet_baseline(nn.Module):

    """
        A MLP with 2 hidden layer

        observation_dim (int): number of observation features
        action_dim (int): Dimension of each action
        seed (int): Random seed
    """

    def __init__(self, observation_dim, action_dim, seed):
        super(QNet_baseline, self).__init__()
        self.seed = torch.manual_seed(seed)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(observation_dim, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 64)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64, action_dim)

    def forward(self, observations):
        """
           Forward propagation of neural network

        """

        x = F.relu(self.fc1(observations))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x


class QNet_3hidden(nn.Module):

    """
        A MLP with 3 hidden layer

        observation_dim (int): number of observation features
        action_dim (int): Dimension of each action
        seed (int): Random seed
    """

    def __init__(self, observation_dim, action_dim, seed):
        super(QNet_3hidden, self).__init__()
        self.seed = torch.manual_seed(seed)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(observation_dim, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 64)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64, 64)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(64, action_dim)

    def forward(self, observations):
        """
           Forward propagation of neural network

        """

        x = F.relu(self.fc1(observations))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))
        x = self.fc4(x)
        return x
```

I used the same code to instantiate both classes. `QNet_baseline` works fine, but I got the following error for `QNet_3hidden`. Why would `QNet_baseline` works but `QNet_3hidden` has an error? What did I miss here? Thanks!

```
/home/workspace/QNetworks.py in __init__(self, observation_dim, action_dim, seed)
     44 
     45     def __init__(self, observation_dim, action_dim, seed):
---> 46         super(QNet_3hidden, self).__init__()
     47         self.seed = torch.manual_seed(seed)
     48         self.fc1 = nn.Linear(observation_dim, 128)

TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Also, below is how the two classes instantiated:

```
class DDQN_Agent():
    """Interacts with and learns from the environment.

    Attributes:
        state_size (int): dimension of each state
        action_size (int): dimension of each action
        seed (int): random seed
    """

    def __init__(self, state_size, action_size, seed, qnet="baseline", filename=None):
        """Initialize an Agent object.

        Args:
            filename: path of .pth file with trained weights
        """
        self.state_size = state_size
        self.action_size = action_size
        self.seed = random.seed(seed)

        # Q-Network
        if qnet=="3hidden":
            self.qnetwork_local = QNet_3hidden(state_size, action_size, seed).to(device)
            self.qnetwork_target = QNet_3hidden(state_size, action_size, seed).to(device)
            self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.qnetwork_local.parameters(), lr=LR)
        else:
            self.qnetwork_local = QNet_baseline(state_size, action_size, seed).to(device)
            self.qnetwork_target = QNet_baseline(state_size, action_size, seed).to(device)
            self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.qnetwork_local.parameters(), lr=LR)

        if filename:
            weights = torch.load(filename)
            self.qnetwork_local.load_state_dict(weights)
            self.qnetwork_target.load_state_dict(weights)

        # Replay memory
        self.memory = ReplayBuffer(action_size, BUFFER_SIZE, BATCH_SIZE, seed)
        # Initialize time step (for updating every UPDATE_EVERY steps)
        self.t_step = 0
```

Comment: Perhaps `nn.Module` is doing something funky during instantiation. You shouldn't really be passing any arguments to `super` so it can figure out itself what it actually needs. Just to `super().__init__()`.

Comment: Could you perhaps show us where you instantiate both classes?

Comment: @Will updated how the classes instantiated. Thanks.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your subclassing. Can you post a little bit more of your exception stacktrace?

Comment: Did you solve it meanwhile?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem, and completely restarting the kernel helped.
As suggested in this [Comment by keitakurita](https://github.com/pytorch/text/issues/226#issuecomment-366491069):

> Are you running the code in a Jupyter notebook and have not restarted the kernel? If so, there's a chance that your kernel is referencing the wrong class.

I suspect this might be the reason because I encountered the error after rewriting the class.

This would also explain why this is a hard-to-reproduce error. Followings a list of similar questions asked to help keep a track of the same:

- [Gitmemory](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/albumentations-team/albumentations/733/714485442)
- [From July '20](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/torchvision-super-imagefolder-self-init-typeerror/88479)
- [From Feb '18](https://github.com/pytorch/text/issues/226)